# Is it necessary to close a Mongodb Change Stream?

Tags: mongodb, express, changestream

I coded the next Node/Express/Mongo script:

```
  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  const stream = require("stream");

  async function main() {

     // CONECTING TO LOCALHOST (REPLICA SET)
     const client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27018");

     try{

       // CONECTION
       await client.connect();

       // EXECUTING MY WATCHER
       console.log("Watching ...");
       await myWatcher(client, 15000);

     } catch (e) {

       // ERROR MANAGEMENT
       console.log(`Error > ${e}`);

     } finally {

       // CLOSING CLIENT CONECTION ???
       await client.close();  << ????

     }
  }main().catch(console.error);

  // MY WATCHER. LISTENING CHANGES FROM MY DATABASE
  async function myWatcher(client, timeInMs, pipeline = []) {

     // TARGET TO WATCH
     const watching = client.db("myDatabase").collection("myCollection").watch(pipeline);

     // WATCHING CHANGES ON TARGET
     watching.on("change", (next) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(next));
        console.log(`Doing my things...`);
     });
     
     // CLOSING THE WATCHER ???
     closeChangeStream(timeInMs, watching);    << ????
  }

  // CHANGE STREAM CLOSER
  function closeChangeStream(timeInMs = 60000, watching) {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           console.log("Closing the change stream");
           watching.close();
           resolve();
       }, timeInMs);
     });
  }
```

So, the goal is to keep always `myWatcher` function in an active state, to watch any database changes and for example, send an user notification when is detected some updating. The `closeChangeStream` function close `myWatcher` function in X seconds after any database changes. So, to keep the `myWatcher` always active, do you recomment not to use the `closeChangeStream` function ??

Another thing. With this goal in mind, to keep always `myWatcher` function in an active state, if I keep the `await client.close();`, my code emits an error: **Topology is closed**, so when I ignore this `await client.close()`, my code works perfectly.  Do you recomment not to use the `await client.close()` function to keep always `myWatcher` function in an active state  ??

Im  a newbee in this topics !

thanks for the advice !

Thanks for help !

Comment: Use backtick ` ` around keywords that you want to format.

Comment: Thanks you my friend !

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB change streams are implemented in a pub/sub paradigm.

Send your application to a friend in the Sudan. Have both you and your friend run the application (that has the change stream implemented). If you open up mongosh and run db.getCollection('myCollection').updateOne({_id: ObjectId("6220ee09197c13d24a7997b7")}, {FirstName: Bob}); both you and your friend will get the console.log for the change stream.

This is assuming you're not running localhost, but you can simulate this with two copies of the applications locally.

The issue comes from going into production and suddenly you have 200 load bearers, 5 developers, etc. running and your watch fires a ton of writes around the globe.

I believe, the practice is to functionize it. Wrap your watch in a function and fire the function when you're about to do a write (and close after you do your associated writes).